# Visual Studio 2005 Build Order

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a Web Application.

Sometimes I want to debug a console app that is within the solution.

Why is it that when I right click on it and select debug, it builds every single webpage and libraries, which takes a while.

When I look at build dependencies for the console app, it lists everything in the solution as the order and tells me to go to build order to change it.

In build order, everything checks out... I only have checked the libraries that this console app needs.

I also tried setting this console app as a start up project. Same thing...

How do I get it so when I want to debug this console app, it only builds that and runs instead of building the entire solution before running?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the dependencies in all your other projects are set correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I would check:

1. Make sure you have no unnecessary project references. This will cause them to be listed as dependencies and be built each time.
2. Also check to see if the your console app is not listed as a project reference to the other projects in the solution.
3. Turn off copy local in your project references. When it has to copies these files to all of the bin folders it takes time.

Comment: Ok that worked except that it still opens up a Development Server for all the web pages at the bottom right taskbar. Is this normal?

Comment: Thats hard to answer because I don't know what your console app is doing. If you are referencing the web app or calling code inside the web app it will start up the dev server. In this case it would be normal.